# JHipster form controls validation not working

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a class structure which looks like the following JDL

```
entity Address {
  address String required,
  city String required,
  postalCode String required,
  country String required,
}

entity MainEntity {
  <some fields>
}

relationship OneToOne {
  MainEntity {addressFirst} to Address,
  MainEntity {addressSecond} to Address
}
```

I generated all the files using `JHipster`.

In the view level, I am trying to insert all the details of `MainEntity` in a single view.

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="mainEntity.addressFirst.address" for="field_addressFirst_address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="field_addressFirst_address"
               [(ngModel)]="mainEntity.addressFirst.address" required maxlength="240"/>
        <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.address?.dirty && editForm.controls.address?.invalid)">
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
                   [hidden]="!editForm.controls.address?.errors?.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
                This field is required.
            </small>
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
                   [hidden]="!editForm.controls.address?.errors?.maxlength" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.maxlength" translateValues="{ max: 240 }">
                This field cannot be longer than 240 characters.
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="mainEntity.addressSecond.address" for="field_addressSecond_address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="field_addressSecond_address"
               [(ngModel)]="mainEntity.addressSecond.address" required maxlength="240"/>
        <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.address?.dirty && editForm.controls.address?.invalid)">
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
                   [hidden]="!editForm.controls.address?.errors?.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
                This field is required.
            </small>
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
                   [hidden]="!editForm.controls.address?.errors?.maxlength" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.maxlength" translateValues="{ max: 240 }">
                This field cannot be longer than 240 characters.
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I am confused how to update the `editForm.controls.address` field to separate the validations for these two fields.

I tried to use `editForm.controls.addressSecond.address` and I got an error which said `addressSecond` is `undefined`.

I cannot even find any declaration of `editForm` or `controls` in the typescript files. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `name` property in the `input` tag. I changed their names to `addressFirstAddress` and `addressSecondAddress`, and their corresponding validation names. The solved code is provided below.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="mainEntity.addressFirst.address" for="field_addressFirst_address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addressFirstAddress" id="field_addressFirst_address"
           [(ngModel)]="mainEntity.addressFirst.address" required maxlength="240"/>
    <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.addressFirstAddress?.dirty && editForm.controls.addressFirstAddress?.invalid)">
        <small class="form-text text-danger"
               [hidden]="!editForm.controls.addressFirstAddress?.errors?.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
            This field is required.
        </small>
        <small class="form-text text-danger"
               [hidden]="!editForm.controls.addressFirstAddress?.errors?.maxlength" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.maxlength" translateValues="{ max: 240 }">
            This field cannot be longer than 240 characters.
        </small>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="mainEntity.addressSecond.address" for="field_addressSecond_address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addressSecondAddress" id="field_addressSecond_address"
           [(ngModel)]="mainEntity.addressSecond.address" required maxlength="240"/>
    <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.addressSecondAddress?.dirty && editForm.controls.addressSecondAddress?.invalid)">
        <small class="form-text text-danger"
               [hidden]="!editForm.controls.addressSecondAddress?.errors?.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
            This field is required.
        </small>
        <small class="form-text text-danger"
               [hidden]="!editForm.controls.addressSecondAddress?.errors?.maxlength" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.maxlength" translateValues="{ max: 240 }">
            This field cannot be longer than 240 characters.
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```